# how to Unserialize form data(serialized by jquery) at server side in .Net?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, serialization

We can use `$( "form" ).serialize();` to post(ajax) form data to server, "single=Single&multiple=Multiple&multiple=Multiple3&check=check2&radio=radio1"

I don't know how to **Unserialize** it.
Although when we use ajax to post serialized form to controller, it will unserialize automatically to object, how can I do it by coding?

Answer (score 0):

If you are also referencing Web API (System.Net.Http.Formatting), you can create a [FormDataCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.formatting.formdatacollection(v=vs.118).aspx) from the string.

```
var fdc = new FormDataCollection("a=1&b=2&c=3");
```

The result is an `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>>`